# running python function with arguments from cmd.exe

Tags: python

I have  Python function that takes 1 arguments

```
def build_ibs(Nthreads,LibCfg):  # Nthreads is int,LibCfg as string
      import os  # module os must be imported
      import subprocess
      import sys
```

I use following in cmd.exe(on Win7) to call it

```
C:>cd C:\SVN\Python Code
C:\SVN\Python Code>C:\Python27\python.exe build_libs(4,'Release')
```

that throws error
   [image]
  using following

```
 C:>cd C:\SVN\Python Code
 C:\SVN\Python Code>C:\Python27\python.exe 4 'Release' # dosn't work
 C:\SVN\Python Code>C:\Python27\python.exe 4 Release   # dosn't work
```

does nothing, and no error is displayed even.

What is the correct way to call it both in cmd.exe or even Python shell command line?
Thanks

sedy

Comment: Did you try to use sys.argv to get the arguments from the command line. https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just call a function from the command line - it must be inside a file. When you type `python filename.py` at the command line, what it does is feed the contents of `filename.py` into the Python interpreter with the namespace set to `__main__`.

So when you type `Python.exe 4 'Release'` it tries to find a file named `4`. Since this file does not exist, Windows returns an Errno 2 - File not found.

Instead, put your code into a file - lets say *test.py*:

*test.py*:

```
def build_libs(Nthreads,LibCfg):  # Nthreads is int,LibCfg as string
      import os  # module os must be imported
      import subprocess
      import sys
      # ...

if __name__=='__main__':
    numthreads = sys.argv[1] # first argument to script - 4
    libconfig = sys.argv[2] # second argument
    # call build_libs however you planned
    build_libs(numthreads, libconfig)
```

Then run from the command line:
`C:\Python27\python.exe test.py 4 Release`
In the directory that test.py is saved in.

*Update:* If you need to use `build_libs` in multiple files, it's best to define it in a module, and then import it. For example:

*mod_libs/__init__.py* - empty file

*mod_libs/core.py*:

```
def build_libs(...):
    ....
    # function definition goes here
```

*test.py*:

```
import sys
import mod_libs
if __name__ == '__main__':
    mod_libs.build_libs(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron, it works and I also got the idea.However, if there were many files that needed to use _build_libs_ then, calling it from within other files would be better than rewriting function definition again and again? in such case, assuming _build_libs_ is  put into a package and imported, would function call remain same as you have shown above?

Comment: Yeah, you can put it into a Python module. I edited the answer to show how you might do that.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to use Python code as in your first attempt, you need to start the Python interpreter.
2. If you want to call a Python function from your OS's command line as in your second attempt, you need to use the proper modules (like `sys.argv` or `argparse`).

For example:

```
C:\SVN\Python Code> py
Python 3.4.2 (v3.4.2:ab2c023a9432, Oct  6 2014, 22:16:31) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import build_libs
>>> build_libs.build_libs(4, 'Release')
```

Or, in your `build_libs.py`, import the `sys` module at the top of the script, and then run the function based on its arguments at the end of the script:

```
import sys

...

print(build_libs(int(sys.argv[1]), sys.argv[2]))
```

Then at your OS's command line:

```
C:\SVN\Python Code> py build_libs 4 Release
```

Comment: Tigerhawk,I tried this but did not work. I have updated question too.